# How to run only the Cucumber scenarios with a certain tag using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I'm new to IntelliJ and Cucumber.

How can I run only scenarios with a certain tag from within IntelliJ?

I have seen there is this command:

```
cucumber --tags @sanity
```

but I prefer using the IDE UI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an Ultimate Edition license handy, but this is how to do it in RubyMine so maybe it will work in IntelliJ:

- go to Run/Debug Configurations
- click + to make a new one and choose Cucumber
- set Mode to 'All features in folder'
- set 'Features folder' to your features folder
- set 'Tags filter' to @yourtag
- hit OK
- click the arrow or hit whatever key combo runs the current Run/Debug config in your keymap to run the scenarios